# How to partition a non-partitioned table on Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, impala

Given a table with 360 days of data, we want to partition it by date to improve performance. Do we need to use following SELECT command for each date? Any more efficient way to do this?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE <new_table> Partition (dt='2015-07-01')
SELECT * from <table> WHERE dt='2015-07-01'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make your table:

```
create  db.my_table(column1 int, column2 string,
                     -- ...
)
comment 'I like paritioned tables'
partitioned by(dt string)
location '/path/to/file';
```

Now you can load the data into dt partitions:

```
insert overwrite into table db.my_table partition (dt) select * from other_table;
```

Comment: dt is converted from another column date_. Can we do this in the second step: INSERT Overwrite Into Table newtable partition (dt) SELECT column1, to_date(date_) AS dt FROM table0 ?

Comment: Yes you can have any query you want as long as it fits the schema you in the create table statement.

Answer (score 1):

If your new table is partitioned by dt (date), you should use [Dynamic Partition](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions#DynamicPartitions-DynamicPartitions). You dont need to specify the specific partition (in this case date). In this way Hive realize all different dates and it makes the partitions automatically.

Remember set these flags:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

Comment: Is your idea same as  @invoketheshell's answer?

Comment: Yes, is the same idea. The only difference is that I would create the table as an external table, in this case if you accidentally drop the table, the data will be still there, in other case the data will be removed. Also remember to use the flags.